# font family in text cells keeps reverting to unwanted default

Tags: text-formatting

I'm using Mma 10 under macOS Sierra to write exam questions for a calculus class. This involves writing a fair bit of text, with interspersed symbols and equations.  The annoying problem is that even though in the Option Inspector I've specified Formatting Options->Font Options->FontFamily: "Chalkboard", every time I hit *Ctrl-9* to enter a symbol or equation, then *Ctrl-0* to get back to text mode, the text font reverts to Arial, the font of the symbol/eqn.

How do I either (a) disable the reversion, or (b) specify that the  symbol/eqn mode use the same "Chalkboard" font as the text?

Comment: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontFamily -> "Chalkboard"]}]]`

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  It works fine once I enter the command in a new notebook, and it stays active on re-opening that notebook.  Now I have two questions: Can I make it default for every notebook without entering the command at the beginning?  and  How could I discover such a lengthy command myself?

Comment: Read a bunch of the questions and answers on this site about stylesheets. That's the answer to (2) and will teach you how to do (1).